# Remote monitoring with java visualvm and JMX

Tags: java, openstack, visualvm, karaf, jvisualvm

I would like to monitor a remotely running java (spring boot) application with jvisualvm (or jconsole). When running locally, I can see the managed beans in both jvisualvm and jconsole. When running remotely I cannot connect. I tried it with several different java processes (e.g. with spring xd). Looking for answers here on SO and on Google did not help.

These are my JAVA_OPTS (on the remote host):

```
$ echo $JAVA_OPTS
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.106.138.210
```

The java version on the remote host (centos linux vm) is:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

The java version on the local machine (Mac OS) is slightly different:

java in windows machine

```
$ java -version    
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
In jvisualvm I add the remote connection as follows (tried both with ssl connection and without):
```

When i connect remote java application through JVISUALVM as like,
 10.106.138.210:9010

I got error like,

```
Cannot connect to 10.106.138.210:9010 service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://10.106.138.210:9010/jmxrmi
```

Please help me

Comment: Does this command run successfully on your Windows host?  `telnet 10.106.138.210 9010`?

Comment: No.. it not worked.. I got connection failed message when i did telnet

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you can't connect due to a networking problem, for example the IP address you're using is incorrect, a firewall is preventing connectivity, or the `java` process you're connecting to isn't actually listening on port 9010.  This command should succeed remotely to indicate connectivity with TCP/IP:

```
telnet 10.106.138.210 9010
```

Reference:

https://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html

Comment: netstat -nlp | grep :9010
                                                                                                                                   tcp6       0      0 :::9010                 :::*                    LISTEN      17503/java

Comment: The process running on the port 9010 in the linux machine

Comment: How can i cross check whether the firewall is preventing or not

Comment: To determine whether or not it's the firewall, try temporarily disabling the firewall on Linux.

Comment: I have disabled the firewall in linux by <br><br>systemctl stop firewalld.service <br> systemctl disable firewalld.service.. Still i cant connect